# Android 2.3.3 MySql Lock wait timeout exceeded SOLUTION

Tags: android, mysql, insert-update

I use mysql 4.1.22 android 2.3.3.

Every operation of Update/Insert lock the table and throw exception "Lock wait timeout exceeded" if autocommit is true. Well: disable autocommit and after execution of statement call commit() from your connection.

Sample Code:

```
   connection.setAutoCommit(false)
   stmt = connection.CreateStatement();
   int ris = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tablename () VALUES ()");
   connection.commit();
   stmt.close();
```

if necessary close connection or continue with another statement.
I hope this help.